# Wordpress REST API - Post Call from a Chrome Extension

Tags: ajax, wordpress, google-chrome-extension, wordpress-rest-api

I developed a chrome extension and I want to store some datas coming from the chrome extension to my wordpress website using REST API.

I have to 2 issues:

1. The first one is that I have an error linked to the fact that there is an interaction between two different domain : "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://groupio.fr/wp-json/groupio/v1/ean/' from origin 'chrome-extension://hafjgepbbnbjcmmkealkikdjlmojdlkf' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value ''."
2. The second one is that I cannot return value to my chrome extension after running a php function from my Wordpress website.

Here is my REST API call from the background.js file of my Chrome Extension:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(response, sender, sendResponse){

        jQuery.ajax({

        type:"POST",
        url: "https://groupio.fr/wp-json/groupio/v1/ean/",
        contentType: 'applcation/json',

        data : {
            ean: "1234567889",
            type: "Product Code"
        },

        success:function(data){

            alert(data);
        },

        error: function(errorThrown){
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
        });

});
```

Here is my new endpoint and Rest API callback function inside the function.php of my theme 
(as you can see I only want to return the exact value without processing anything) - and it does not work :

```
function my_awesome_func( $data ) {

    return $data['ean'];
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'groupio/v1', '/ean/', array(
    'methods' => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'my_awesome_func',
  ) );
} );
```

Comment: Anyone can help me about this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

The Access-Control-Allow-Origin is being set to blank because the request is not being sent from a supported protocol. Currently WordPress is validating this list against these items:

```
$protocols = array( 'http', 'https', 'ftp', 'ftps', 'mailto', 'news', 'irc', 'gopher', 'nntp', 'feed', 'telnet', 'mms', 'rtsp', 'sms', 'svn', 'tel', 'fax', 'xmpp', 'webcal', 'urn' );
```

The good news is that you can make changes to this list via the "kses_allowed_protocols" filter. So in your WordPress plugin or functions file, add in the following to add support for "chrome-extension"

```
add_filter( 'kses_allowed_protocols', function ( $protocols ) {
    $protocols[] = 'chrome-extension';
    return $protocols;
} );
```

This should allow the header to get correctly set. I think that once that is done, you will get some results from your API.